# Blender OSL and P (position) relative to object scale

Tags: shader, blender

I'm working on shaders in blender / cycles Script node.
I'm testing the "noise texture" shader, taken directly from blender source code and simply put in a Script node.

I can't understand how global P is managed, in the stock Noise Texture node and in the Script node, relative to object scale.

If I scale the object when the stock Noise Texture node is applied, the texture doesn't change (scales according to the object).

But if I scale the object when the scripted shader is applied, the texture changes... it looks like the texture doesn't scale, just wraps the object differently, so it looks "smaller" relative to the object if I scale it up, or larger if I scale the object down.

It's like blender gives the object scale property to the Noise Texture, but doesn't give it to the Script node.

Any informations or ideas how to solve it?

I can manually change a shader's Scale property, but I'm looking for a more robust solution, if any, because I gotta do lot of tests on different models.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i found the correct way from https://blendersushi.blogspot.com/2013/08/osl-shader-writing-journey-to-unknown.html

> TRANSFORM TEXTURE WITH OBJECT
> To avoid "texture swimming", we need to
> assign Texture Space to our OSL Texture. We can either doing it
> directly inside OSL or using Blender Cycles Texture Coordinate node
> and Mapping node that goes into the Vector position.
>
> If you add a single code below, it will properly assign Texture Space
> to the "object" space.
>
> `point p = transform("object", P);`